# Dropdown center text

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I am making a menu with a dropdown submenu and I have a problem: I can't center align the the text of the submenu items.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #4c4e5a;
}

.menu li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
}

.menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  background-color: #1f2024;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[My problem looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfwTg.png)

So, how can I center that text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `padding:0;` on `menu ul`

```
.menu ul {
    background-color: #1f2024;
    display: block;
    padding: 0;/*Add This Property*/
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0bcjod8c/

Answer (score 0):

Add `padding:0px;width:100%;` on *.menu ul* and add a line `.menu ul li{text-align:center;width:100%;}`

```
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
body {
            margin:0px;
            padding:0px;
}
.menu {
            display:inline-block;
            width:100%;
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #4c4e5a;
}
.menu li {
            position: relative;
            list-style-type: none;
            float: left;
}
.menu li a {
            display:inline-block;
            padding: 15px 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
}
.menu ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            padding:0px;width:100%;
            top:48px;
            background-color: #1f2024;
}
.menu ul li{text-align:center;width:100%;}
.menu ul li a {
            display:inline-block;
            width:auto;
            padding:10px;
            text-align:center;
}
.menu li:hover > ul {
            display:block;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Cristi-Cazan Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more class to your CSS stylesheet

```
.menu ul li {
            text-align:center;
            width: 100%;
}
```

This should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown list items should have width:100%;

```
.menu li:hover > ul li {
        display:block;
        width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a chain for ul and li properties just like following css because i need to catch `.menu li > ul > li`.

I think it will probably work for you.

Update css

```
.menu li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu li:hover > ul {
   display: block;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.menu {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #4c4e5a;
}

.menu li {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  background-color: #1f2024;
}

.menu li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.menu li:hover>ul {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="#" id="active">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Dropdown</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```